# Error while nesting a SliverList inside a StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-sliver, stream-builder

I am using below code in my flutter application with firestore as database backend, earlier the sliver effect was working fine, but when I re-installed the application and then again tested then I faced the below error upon re-launch of the application, how should I resolve it?

**ERROR**

> A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a
>   child of type RenderErrorBox.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Do something
                }),
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            floating: true,
            pinned: false,
            snap: true,
            elevation: 50,
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text('Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    )),
                background: Image.network(
                  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/443356/pexels-photo-443356.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
          ),


          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: query.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              if (!snapshot.hasData){
                return Center(child: Text("Loading"));
              }
              return SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) {


                          String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['itemTitle'];


          return  CardItem(itemTitle:itemTitle );



                    },
                    childCount:
                    snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 0,
                  ));
            },
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: you cannot `return Center(child: Text("Loading"));` - you have to return a sliver

Comment: but actually why not to swap those two? so it looks like: `StreamBuilder > CustomScrollView` ?

Comment: @pskink I will try that

Comment: Try changing Center(child: Text("Loading")) for SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: Text("Loading")))

Comment: snapshot.data.documents.length did you manage to get count..?

Comment: Thkank you EdwynZn works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The following comment helped me:

> You cannot return Center(child: Text("Loading")); - you have to return
> a sliver – pskink - Jun 13 '20 at 4:22.

You should wrap the `Center` widget with a widget that extends the abstract class `RenderSliver`.

Example:

```
SliverFillRemaining(child:  Center(child: Text("Loading")));
```